# Filtering function running one step too late

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm building a component to filter an array of data.

There are 2 filters, one for the Team and one for the location. When each of the dropdowns are changed I'm changing a state variable for team and location and then running the filter function.

For some reason, the filter is running one step too late.

*As an example* -  if I choose Team A, nothing will update. If I then choose Team B the `careersDataFiltered` variable will show Team A. If I choose Team C it'll then show Team B's data.

Its almost like its running one step too late.

You can see from the code that I'm running the filter after the state variables have been set which is why this is a bit of head-scratcher for me.

```
import React, { useState } from "react"

import { motion, AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion"

const careersData = [
  {
    name: "X Job Title",
    url: "/url/x",
    team: "Team a",
    location: "London",
  },
  {
    name: "M Job Title",
    url: "/url/m",
    team: "Team a",
    location: "London",
  },
  {
    name: "B Job Title",
    url: "/url/b",
    team: "Team c",
    location: "Sheffield",
  },
  {
    name: "A Job Title",
    url: "/url/a",
    team: "Team b",
    location: "London",
  },
  {
    name: "F Job Title",
    url: "/url/f",
    team: "Team b",
    location: "Sheffield",
  },
  {
    name: "C Job Title",
    url: "/url/c",
    team: "Team c",
    location: "London",
  },
  {
    name: "Q Job Title",
    url: "/url/q",
    team: "Team a",
    location: "Sheffield",
  },
]

const uniqueTeams = []
const uniqueLocations = []

// Build the unique values
if (careersData !== null) {
  careersData.map(career => {
    if (uniqueTeams.indexOf(career.team) === -1) {
      return uniqueTeams.push(career.team)
    }
  })
}

if (careersData !== null) {
  careersData.map(career => {
    if (uniqueLocations.indexOf(career.location) === -1) {
      return uniqueLocations.push(career.location)
    }
  })
}

// reorder ready for output
uniqueTeams.sort()
uniqueLocations.sort()

const CurrentVacancies = () => {
  const [careersDataFiltered, setCareersDataFiltered] = useState(careersData)
  const [filterTeam, setFilterTeam] = useState("")
  const [filterLocation, setFilterLocation] = useState("")

  // filter array based on values
  const runFilter = () => {
    // reset the filter data
    setCareersDataFiltered(careersData)

    if (filterTeam !== "") {
      setCareersDataFiltered(
        careersDataFiltered.filter(career => career.team === filterTeam)
      )
    }
    if (filterLocation !== "") {
      careersDataFiltered(
        careersDataFiltered.filter(career => career.location === filterLocation)
      )
    }
    console.log(careersDataFiltered)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex">
        <h2 className="mr-auto">Current Vacancies</h2>
        <div className="">
          <select
            onChange={e => {
              setFilterTeam(e.target.value)
              runFilter()
            }}
          >
            <option value="">Team</option>
            {uniqueTeams.map(team => (
              <option key={team} value={team}>
                {team}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
          <select
            onChange={e => {
              setFilterLocation(e.target.value)
              runFilter()
            }}
          >
            <option value="">Location</option>
            {uniqueLocations.map(location => (
              <option key={location} value={location}>
                {location}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <AnimatePresence>
          {careersDataFiltered.map((career, index) => (
            <motion.div
              key={index}
              initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
              animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
              exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
              positionTransition
            >
              <div>
                <div className="text-sm">
                  {career.name} - {career.team} | {career.location}
                </div>
              </div>
            </motion.div>
          ))}
        </AnimatePresence>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default CurrentVacancies
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all Your code has some errors, you should use `setCareersDataFiltered()` in second if statement of `runFilter()`. Also `setCareersDataFiltered()` is `async` so you can not use `careersDataFiltered` right after you call `setCareersDataFiltered()`. It's same for call to `setFilterTeam()` because you are using `filterTeam` in `runFilter()` so you can not call `runFilter()` after your call to `setFilterTeam()` because your data is not guaranteed to be updated. It's also true for `setFilterLocation()`.

Put `runFilter()` inside `useEffect()` so it will call it when any dependencies of `runFilter()` changes.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    runFilter();
  }, [runFilter]);
```

Also change `runFilter()` as follow and use `useCallback()` to prevent re-render loop.

```
// filter array based on values
  const runFilter = useCallback(() => {
    let filter = careersData;
    if (filterTeam !== "") {
      filter = filter.filter(career => career.team === filterTeam);
    }
    if (filterLocation !== "") {
      filter = filter.filter(career => career.location === filterLocation);
    }
    setCareersDataFiltered(filter);
  }, [filterLocation, filterTeam]);
```

At the end remove any manual call to `runFilter()`;

As a hint I think your filter logic has a bug also because I can set team to A and then it only show me A but if I set location it apply location filter and ignore A filter and it's because of `async` issue. So if you want to apply both filters at the same time you should mix two if statements in `runFilter()`. I've mixed filters and wrote a new filter routine.

[Here is my working demo version](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-psfi8?file=/src/TodoApp.js:1524-1541)

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, this problem could be related on how you set `careersDataFiltered` in function `runFilter`. For my personal experience, read and set state directly is never a good idea. Try to change `runFilter` like this:

```
const runFilter = () => {
let temp_careersDataFiltered = _.cloneDeep(careersData); //here you have to clone deep careersData because javascript keep reference (I use cloneDeep from lodash)

if (filterTeam !== "") {
  temp_careersDataFiltered = careersData.filter(career => career.team === filterTeam)
}
if (filterLocation !== "") {
  temp_careersDataFiltered = careersData.filter(career => career.location === filterLocation)

}

setCareersDataFiltered(
    temp_careersDataFiltered 
)
console.log(temp_careersDataFiltered) 
}
```

Explanation: since you don't have certainty that after call `setCareersDataFiltered` value of `careersDataFiltered` is immediately available, apply filters to `temp_careersDataFiltered` temporary array and in the end set `careersDataFiltered` to re-render the component.
I'm cloning `careersData` because you know javascript works with reference and if you write `let temp_careersDataFiltered = careersData` if you modify `temp_careersDataFiltered` infact you are modifying `careersData` also.